# Creating python script to split selected lines at a set length

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, splitting

I have been having trouble trying to come up with a python script that will go through a polyline feature class representing a river system and **split all the streams intersecting with a central river at distance of 2km**. The added difficulty is that any given stream can be made up of multiple polyline segments. Thus if a stream that intersects with the central river is made up of 2 line segments 1.5km long, the first would need to be unclipped, and the second after 0.5 km.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to write a script that will accomplish this? I know  **positionAlongLine** tool might help but I am not sure how to implement it.

[image]

Comment: "The added difficulty is that any given stream can be made up of multiple polyline segments." - Dissolving the stream segments into single features would be a good start to avoid that problem.

Comment: How is the central river designated? Can the tributaries fork as well?

Comment: Could you please illustrate on a picture how the polylines should be split and how you define the central river / streams (an attribute value?)

Comment: @Adam Thanks for the tip, dissolving them will definitely make things easier

Comment: @EmilBrundage The central river is designated by all the features sharing the rivers name in the attribute table. An yes the tributaries often do fork before 2km unfortunately

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov graphic added for illustration

Comment: Are there lots of main rivers with tributaries or just one in the feature class? If there are multiple main rivers, are the main rivers and tributaries differentiated somehow? What coordinate system is the feature class in?

Comment: @EmilBrundage There are several main rivers, the tributaries can be differentiated from the main rivers by the name attributes they have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this question ever got resolved, I apologize Soupoder. The idea I have doesn't require arcpy.

1) Create a [selection](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/select.htm) of central trunk rivers and export them as a separate feature class. Create a [buffer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/buffer.htm) around your central trunk rivers at 2km.

[image: One]

2) Use [Feature to Line](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/feature-to-line.htm) to split your side branches with the 2km buffer, adding both feature classes as "Input Features" in the tool.

[image: Two]

3) Since polylines from both the input side branches *and* buffer will be present in the tool output, [Select by Location](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/map/working-with-layers/using-select-by-location.htm) those lines that "share a line segment with" the original buffer feature class and delete them in Editor.

[image: Three]

You'll need an Advanced license for this workflow. Otherwise, we'll have to resort to some fancy arcpy to mimic the "Feature to Line", but let us know if this is the answer you were looking for.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, my office just got an upgraded advanced license and this workflow solved the problem nicely.